# htaccess rewriterule 2 parameters in url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having an issue with rewriting an url via `.htaccess`,
I have the following url

```
 www.website.com/people.php?search=search
```

via `htaccess` I turn it into `.../people/search`

```
 RewriteRule ^people/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ people.php?search=$1
 RewriteRule ^people/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ people.php?search=$1search=$1
```

in the url the user can also add a location which should be

```
 www.website.com/people.php?search=something&&location=something
```

How can I use rewrite rule to add the two search parameters to the new rewrite url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be your 2nd rule

```
RewriteRule ^people/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ people.php?search=$1&location=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

It rewrites "/people/foo/bar" to "/people.php?search=foo&location=bar"

Try :

```
RewriteRule ^people/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ people.php?search=$1&location=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^people/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ people.php?search=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```